# What is the shape of mathematical universe?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Shape? At the usual mathematical literature when we can discuss about the shape of a "space" that we have a kind of "topography" on it. For example a topology, metric, geometry, etc.
Note that for example: we can define an "unformal" topology on proper class of $Ord$ which any continuous map $f:Ord\longrightarrow Ord$ in the sense of $\forall \alpha\in limord~~~f(\alpha)=\bigcup_{\beta \in \alpha} f(\beta)$ be continuous in the sense of this topology. Now the main question is:

**Main Question:** Is there any known "non trivial" metric, topology,... on the proper class of all sets or other proper classes like $HOD$, $L$?

**Remark:** Non trivial in the above question means "a topology, metric,... which the proof of being a topology or metric needs an essential use of the special properties of the ground proper class and this definition doesn't work for every collection of sets."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an answer to this for the universe of constructive mathematics. According to Martín Escardó, a universe of Martin-Löf type theory has indiscrete topology, constructively. He has a [draft](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/universe-indiscrete-and-rice.pdf) about it, and [some slides](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/.talks/4WFT/escardo-4WFT.pdf) at his web-page.